# How to implement template throughout nested classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I am trying to implement binary tree using following code, I want to create node of the type passed inside the binary tree automatically but I just can't figure out how to do it. Please help. Thanks

```
template <typename X>
class binaryTree{
  template <typename X>
  class node{
    X data;
    node<X>* left;
    node<X>* right;
 };
};
```

Comment: Remove the `template <typename X>` from `class node`. `X` from `binaryTree` will be implicitly available in all inner classes.

Comment: @DeiDei doesn't work that way either.

Comment: Well, what's the problem? You haven't given us what errors you are getting, or where they occur. "Doesn't work" is not a description of the problem. There's no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `template <typename X>`. Also you may consider deleting the `left` and the `right` pointer in the destructor if each node owns its left and right node.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
class binaryTree
{
public:

    class node
    {

    public:

        X data;
        node *left;
        node *right;

        ~node()
        {
            delete left;
            delete right;
        }
    };

    node root;
};

int main()
{
    binaryTree<int> tree{
        binaryTree<int>::node{ 
            1,
            new binaryTree<int>::node {2, nullptr, nullptr},
            new binaryTree<int>::node {3, nullptr, nullptr}
        }
    };

    auto& root = tree.root;
    std::cout << root.data << '\n' << root.left->data << '\n' << root.right->data << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```